# udev rules to identify a USB storage media?

Tags: usb, media, ude

I need to execute a command once a usb storage media is inserted. But I don't want to identify the device by the device file, e.g `/dev/sdcX`.

So I can't use filters like `KERNEL=="sd?"`

Is there any other identifier I could use, maybe the `serial number` of the USB storage media?
(I'm not even sure how to read them with udev)